# Energy conservation and calculating second cosmic velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, satellites

I am curious about such a thing.
While calculating second cosmic speed we consider this equation:
$$E = \frac{mv^2}{2} - G\frac{M_E m}{r_E}$$

which we say must be $0$, when the satellite escapes from the earth.
Why is this not against energy conversation?
The total mechanical energy is $E_\rm{pot} + E_\rm{kin} = const$, so it will not possibly become $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not against the law of conservation of mechanical energy provided you don't consider the air resistance.

We use the law of conservation of mechanical energy in this case as shown below :-$$U_i+K_i=U_f+K_f$$ $$\Rightarrow-\frac{GM_em}{R_e}+\frac{1}{2}mv^2=0+0$$ $$\Rightarrow\frac{GM_em}{R_e}=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$$ $$\Rightarrow v=\sqrt\frac{2GM_e}{R_e}\approx 11.2km/s$$

From the second equation itself, it is clear that the total mechanical energy of the system is zero as you said. But this is true, not only when the object escapes the earth's gravitational field, but at all times, including the moment when the object starts from the surface of the earth with second celestial velocity. The total mechanical energy $E_t=U+K$ of the system may be zero at all times, there is no problem with that. In this case, $E = \frac{1}{2} mv^2 - \frac{GM_E m}{r}$ will be zero at all times as from the third equation (though I wrote it only for the moment when the object starts from the earth's surface with second cosmic velocity), the two terms are equal in magnitude and they cancel out each other (You may try it at any arbitrary distance from the earth's centre. You will get the same result).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! good explanation.